# BeautifulSoup - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror, callable-object

Can anyone explain to me why am I getting this error message? I have the exact same code in another project but after creating a new venv and install `requests, bs4 and html.parser` I get this message. I don't understand, at all.

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
import html.parser

source = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: you should use BeautifulSoup class. But you imported the module as BeautifulSoup. Change the 2nd line. `import bs4 as BeautifulSoup` to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to change your bs4 import. Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html.parser

source = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

To explain what was wrong, basically you were importing the entire bs4 module in as BeautifulSoup, when you actually wanted to import the BeautifulSoup class *from* the bs4 module.