# 'module' object is not callable in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
!pip install bs4
!pip install html5lib
import pandas as pd
!pip install lxml
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

url = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0220EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/project/netflix_data_webpage.html"

data=requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html5lib')
```

i am getting module is not Callable, kindly anyone help me

want to parse the data

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637168/beautifulsoup-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Answer (score 1):

You are importing BeautifulSoup incorrectly, please change it to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`